# JBoss Microblogging - Is there one?

Tags: jboss, microblogging

Simple(ish) question, is anyone aware of a microblogging service I can run on a JBOSS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at Collabinate (http://www.collabinate.com).  If the hosted service doesn't suit you, the core engine is open source at https://github.com/Collabinate/Collabinate.